# EPSG codes and water level datums

Tags: well-known-text, epsg

I'm curious if, and how, people use EPSG defined water level vertical datums such as [Mean Low Water](http://epsg.io/1091-datum).

There is specific guidance to **not** use the OGP EPSG definition:

> Remarks: Users are advised to not use this generic vertical datum but to define explicit realisations of MLW by specifying location and epoch, for instance "MLW at xxx during yyyy-yyyy".

Which is a blanket statement across all water level vertical datums sourced from the IHO Dictionary, UK Hydrographic Office, and Canadian Hydrographic Service.

Is there a common convention, especially with WKT, to express a datum as a realization of an EPSG defined datum?